# How can I find the effect size of a 2x2 contingency table where chi square test is not applicable?

Tags: r, statistics, contingency, significance

I have a dataset that contains the number of times visitors to two variants of a website (site1 and site2) bought something or left without buying. The visitors are 200 per site.

Now, as showed in this picture,

[image]

I have one cell in which the number is smaller than 5. Therefore I can't use the chi square test. I used the Fisher's exact test who gives me the odds ratio. But I don't know how to find the exact effect size.

Is there a way to calculate it or a R function to find it?

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: I think my answer is well written and explains my problem. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 1):

The effect size is just the difference in percentage of success:

```
x[1, ] / colSums(x)
# site1 site2 
# 0.025 0.015

diff(x[1, ] / colSums(x))
# site2 
# -0.01
```

Comment: Thank you Gregor :) Can you please explain to me the reasoning behind this? And the reason why it should work?

Comment: Can you be more specific  about what doesn't make sense? One site has 2.5% buy, another one has 1.5% buy. The difference between them (the effect of switching from one to the other) is 2.5% - 1.5% = 1% (make it negative to switch the other way). If you have further conceptual questions, perhaps try asking at stats.stackexchange, as it's not really a programming problem.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I had never calculated the effect size in this way before. That's why it's new for me. So since 0.025 - 0.015 = 0.01, the effect size is small which means that there is no difference between the two sites. Am I interpreting it in the right way?

Comment: Well, lots of loaded terms. The effect size is 1% point. Whether that sounds small or large depends on what you're talking about. If changing the font size on a button on your website increases sales by 1% point, that sounds pretty good. If it's a bigger more expensive change, it might not be worth if for a 1% point increase. The effect size, by itself, doesn't take sample size into account at all--it's just the observed difference.

Comment: That's why you ran your Fisher's Exact Test. Statistical tests like that *never* tell you "there is no difference". The question they answer is more-or-less "is there plausible evidence for a difference", and in this case the answer is "Not enough evidence to conclude there is a difference". Whether or not there is evidence for a difference depends on the size of the difference *and* the size of the sample.

Comment: You can play around with numbers (look up "power analysis" for a systematic way to do this), and you can see that if your sample size was ~10x larger, than this 1% point difference would be *statistically* significant. But that's solely about the detectability of the difference, it says nothing about whether the difference is big enough to be *practically* important.